# How do i wrap a <li></li> around each anchor tag dynamically?

Tags: php, html

This is my text string, What i want is wrap a `<li></li>` around each anchor tag dynamically.

**Ex:-**

```
<li><a href="#"><b>\'Oz, un mundo de fantasa\'</b>: Clip con Weisz y Kunis</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><b>\'The Call\'</b>: 2 Trailer</a></li>




$text = '<a href="#"><b>\'Oz, un mundo de fantasa\'</b>: Clip con Weisz y Kunis</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'The Call\'</b>: 2 Trailer</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Jack, el Cazagigantes\'</b>: Cartel para Espaa</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Spring Breakers\'</b>: Trailer sin Censura</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Los Croods\'</b>: Anuncios de Tv</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'The Way, Way Back\'</b>: Fecha de Estreno</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Los Vengadores 2\'</b>: Thanos!!</a>';
```

Comment: Using PHP or javascript?

Comment: There is no build in function to do this.

Comment: if php use a preg replace and search via regular expression

Comment: You could use str_replace() and search for "<a" and "</a>".

Comment: not sure exactly waht/why you're trying to acheive, but instead of a var (`$text`) could you use an array? Then `foreach` the array appending the tags before and after as required. Or, can't you just add them to the var `$text` with the rest of the data? Or seek a more dynamic method of creating a link list (class, function, etc)

Comment: it is better to use `<a href` instead of `<a`

Comment: @krishna Why so? The OP wants to wrap `<a>` tags with `<li></li>` tags, this it technically has nothing to do with the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$text = str_replace("<a", "<li><a", str_replace('</a>', '</a></li>', $text));
```

Should do it.

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = str_replace("<a href", "<li><a href", $text);
$text = str_replace("</a>", "</a></li>", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you desire to use regular expressions something like this could work as well..

```
$text = '<a href="#"><b>\'Oz, un mundo de fantasa\'</b>: Clip con Weisz y Kunis</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'The Call\'</b>: 2 Trailer</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Jack, el Cazagigantes\'</b>: Cartel para Espaa</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Spring Breakers\'</b>: Trailer sin Censura</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Los Croods\'</b>: Anuncios de Tv</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'The Way, Way Back\'</b>: Fecha de Estreno</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Los Vengadores 2\'</b>: Thanos!!</a>';

$pattern = '/\s*(<a.*<\/a>)*/';

$replacement = '<li>${1}</li>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<a href="#"><b>\'Oz, un mundo de fantasa\'</b>: Clip con Weisz y Kunis</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'The Call\'</b>: 2 Trailer</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Jack, el Cazagigantes\'</b>: Cartel para Espaa</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Spring Breakers\'</b>: Trailer sin Censura</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Los Croods\'</b>: Anuncios de Tv</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'The Way, Way Back\'</b>: Fecha de Estreno</a>
    <a href="#"><b>\'Los Vengadores 2\'</b>: Thanos!!</a>';

$string1= Array("<a", "</a>");
$string2= Array("<li><a","</a></li>");
echo str_replace($string1, $string2, $text);
```